# Как проверить блок на отсутствие события click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, по которому может произойти событие клик. Как можно проверить на отсутствие данного события в течении 5 секунд. То есть, если никто на блок за 5 сек не нажал выводим `alert()`.
Можно ли это сделать средствами *jquery*?

Comment: Запускаете таймер, если клик был, то перезапускаете. Ну и слово "отсутствие" поправьте...

Comment: _отсутствие данного события в течении 5 секунд_ начиная с какого события?

Comment: @Grundy c последнего клика. Если пользователь за 5 секунд не клацнет алерт. А если клацнет то проверка откладывается на 5 секунд. Сама проверка начинается по таймеру каждые 5 секунд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var timeout = null;
$('div').click(function(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = setTimeout(function() { alert('CLICK ME!!!'); }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для случая ожидания клика с момента загрузки документа:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var $block = $('.block');                                    // нахожу нужный блок
  var $clicked = 0;                                            // обнуляю статус нажатия на блок
  $(window).click(function(event) {                            // слушаю нажатие куда-либо
    if ( event.target.className == $block.attr('class') ) {    // если нажатие на искомый блок
      $clicked = 1;                                            // меняю статус нажатой переменной
      console.log('clicked');
    }
  })
  setTimeout(function() {                                     // запускаю функцию, которая через 5 секунд выведет alert в случае нажатия на блок
    if ($clicked == 1) {
      alert('detected');
      console.log('detected');
    } else {
      console.log('not detected');
    }
  }, 5000);
  
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```